# Best GWT chart plugin - with specific needs!

Tags: gwt, charts, variable-assignment

We are about to do large scale school asignment in GWT.

One part is doing charts - histrograms - but we have very specific needs:
a) Charts must be dynamic - zooming and scrolling like Googel finance charts
b) Must support more data sets
c) Must support more Y axis (each dataset it's own)
d) Must be dynamicly changable from code

X axis is allways time.

--> it will be very much like Google finance chart, but with more Z axis (labels and scales)

Any idea what supports that?

Comment: Check out Protovis-GWT. Might have what you're looking for: http://web.uvic.ca/~lgrammel/blog/protovis-gwt/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be Fusion chart is the charts you are looking for.

here is the link [Fusion Charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/)

Comment: If license is an issue than go for Dygraphs charts [http://dygraphs.com/]

Comment: +1 for dygraph. I modified it and use it actually as a scatterplot.